# xamarin forms capture listview from button click

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms

My code below displays a listview, when button 'Please play your order' is clicked, the function ButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e) is hit. How can I capture the entire listview from the ButtonPressed function...

I have tried something like

```
    void ButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var listView = (ListView)sender;//but this did not work
}





 <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CompletedList}" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None">
                    <ListView.Header>
                        <Button Text="Please place your order" Clicked="ButtonPressed"/>
                    </ListView.Header>
                    <ListView.Footer>
                    <Label x:Name="Items" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" Margin="20,20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    </ListView.Footer>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding I_D}" VerticalOptions="End" IsVisible="False"/>

                                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding NameOfProduct}" VerticalOptions="End"/>                     
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
```

Comment: your ListView is bound to CompletedList, so you really just need to access that variable, not the ListView itself.  If you really need to access the ListView itself, just assign it a name and refer to it that way.

Comment: Yes but I was having trouble finding the correct syntax so for example would it be e.CompletedList?, which isnt working

Comment: no, it's not passed as an argument to the handler.  It depends on if it's defined as a property on your page, or on your VM, etc.  How is your BindingContext set?

Comment: ahh yes ok...I got it from the BindingContext of the listView. Thanks again Jason, if you want the marked answer, write it up and ill tick it. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `ListView` is bound to `CompletedList`, so you really just need to access that variable, not the `ListView` itself.